# using KQL to Identify the absence of a value within a JSON message

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am storing JSON messages within an ADX table. The datatype of the JSON column is a string. Within the JSON message is an array that looks like this

```
"FilingEntities": [
        {
            "FilingEntity": 0,
            "FilingMethod": 1,
            "FilingSubMethod": -1
        },
        {
            "FilingEntity": 29,
            "FilingMethod": 1,
            "FilingSubMethod": -1
        },
        {
            "FilingEntity": 66,
            "FilingMethod": 2,
            "FilingSubMethod": -1
        }
    ]
```

what I am trying to do is write a query that identifies the messages where there is only one instance of a filing array. For example, it looks like this

```
"FilingEntities": [
        {
            "FilingEntity": 0,
            "FilingMethod": 1,
            "FilingSubMethod": -1
        }
    ]
```

So far I have been trying to just get the JSON parsed using

```
EventReceivedRaw
| extend DynamicJson = todynamic(JSONRaw)
| mv-expand DynamicJson
| project UniqueEventGuid, TimeStampInCST, DynamicJson, JSONRaw
```

but can't really figure out how to interrogate the message to get to the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The datatype of the JSON column is a string

for efficiency, you should strongly consider re-typing this column to be [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic), so that you don't have to do query-time parsing.

> what I am trying to do is write a query that identifies the messages where there is only one instance of a filing array

you could use the [`array_length()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraylengthfunction) function.

for example:

```
EventReceivedRaw
| extend DynamicJson = todynamic(JSONRaw)
| where array_length(DynamicJson.FilingEntities) == 1
| project UniqueEventGuid, TimeStampInCST, DynamicJson, JSONRaw
```